# Do flat resolutions guarantee the existence of Tor (without enough projectives)?

Tags: derived-categories, derived-functors, quasi-coherent-modules

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category with a symmetric monoidal structure $\otimes$. Suppose that $\mathcal A$ **does not have enough projectives**, but every object has a flat resolution  Then, is the existence of the Tor guaranteed?

Comment: Are you asking about Tor in the sense of universal $\delta$-functors? If so, can't you use the effaceability criterion? (I suppose one might have to ask for a _functorial_ flat resolution to ensure that one really gets a functor...)